# How to create time series plot with an ordinal categorical data on the y-axis - Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I would like some assistance creating a time-series plot with the y-values being an ordinal categorical value.
What I want - time values along the x-axis and ordinal categories (A,B,C,D,E) along the y-axis.
[attempt 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BsK0H.png)

What I tried - In the link above, I made a line chart (hid the lines) and on the y-axis I tried mapping A->5, B->4 etc... which worked, but I don't know how to change the labels on the y-axis to A, B, C, etc...

If there is any easier/better way to do this, it would be muchly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could it be a scatter plot? Is the X axis a true time axis? It looks categorical to me, even thought the categories might represent time periods. Will there be times with no data that need to be included (which would mean a real time axis might be needed). 
You could just put a text box in front of the labels on the y axis of course.

Comment: It could definitely be a scatter plot. You are correct, the x-axis it not a true time axis and could be considered categorical.
Indeed, I ended up just hiding the y-axis and placing a text box on the y-labels. It would still be good to know how I can do it properly! Cheers.